# How to implement a Quick Sort in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have tried to do it but I can't figure it out. I have this Quick Sort that is searching at index 1 but how to I change the string at that index to ints?

```
def quick_sort(list):
    if not list:
        return list
    pivot = list[0]
    lesser = quick_sort([x for x in list[1:] if x[1] < pivot[1]], 1)
    greater = quick_sort([x for x in list[1:] if x[1] >= pivot[1]], 1)
    return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

Any help out there?

Comment: Is it a list of strings? Or a list of integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here try this out.

```
def quick_sort(list):
    if not list: 
        return list 
    pivot = list[0] 
    lesser = quick_sort([x for x in list[1:] if float(x[1]) < float(pivot[1])], 1) 
    greater = quick_sort([x for x in list[1:] if float(x[1]) >= float(pivot[1])], 1) 
    return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @jonrsharpe, I forgot that hanging return statment!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `index` variable:

```
def quick_sort(list):
    if not list:
        return list
    pivot = list[0]
    lesser = quick_sort([x for x in list[1:] if x < pivot])
    greater = quick_sort([x for x in list[1:] if x >= pivot])
    return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```